# Need error box if no question mark is input

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a magic 8 ball and need to display the following:

> If the same question is asked twice in a row, or if the question doesn’t end with a “?”, give appropriate error messages using the Alert function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body style="background-color:black">

  <font size=+ 4 color="white">Magic 8 Ball</font>

  <script>
    <!-- Begin
    var answers = new Array(
      "Ask again later…",
      "Yes",
      "No",
      "It appears to be so",
      "Reply is hazy, please try again",
      "Yes, definitely",
      "What is it you really want to know?",
      "Outlook is good",
      "My sources say no",
      "Signs point to yes",
      "Don’t count on it",
      "Cannot predict now",
      "As I see it, yes",
      "Better not tell you now",
      "Concentrate and ask again",
    );

    function fortune() {
      num = Math.round((answers.length - 1) * Math.random());
      return answers[num];
    }
    //  End -->

  </script>

  <form>
    <b style="color:white">What would you like to know?</b>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <input type=text name=question size=35>

    <input type=button name=ask value="Ask the 8 ball" onClick="if 
(this.form.question.value!='') this.form.answer.value = fortune();"><b style="color:white">

<br>The 8 ball says:</b>
    <br>

    <br>
    <input type=text name=answer size=35>
  </form>
```

Comment: can you post the code you already wrote?

Comment: Impossible to help with the information provided. What specifically are you having an issue with? Please post the current code and an explicit question.

Comment: Can you provide your code please?

Comment: Just edited original question with my code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is this a homework assignment or project you have to do for a course/class?

Comment: Put the question in a variable, compare it next time you call the function. As for the question mark, an `indexOf` probably does enough for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the previous question in a variable and compare on each turn. Something like below. Change the code to suit your needs, but just so you get an idea.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body style="background-color:black">

  <font size=+ 4 color="white">Magic 8 Ball</font>

  <script>
    <!-- Begin
    var previousQuestion = null;
    var answers = new Array(
      "Ask again later…",
      "Yes",
      "No",
      "It appears to be so",
      "Reply is hazy, please try again",
      "Yes, definitely",
      "What is it you really want to know?",
      "Outlook is good",
      "My sources say no",
      "Signs point to yes",
      "Don’t count on it",
      "Cannot predict now",
      "As I see it, yes",
      "Better not tell you now",
      "Concentrate and ask again",
    );
    
    //make this function take a string parameter that will be the users submitted question
    function fortune(question) {
      var validQuestion = true;
      //check if the string meets our criteria
      if (question === previousQuestion || question.slice(-1) != "?") {
        validQuestion = false;
      }
      //if string is invalid, no need to continue
      if (!validQuestion) {
        //give user error alert
        alert("Ask a new question or include question mark");
        //"reset" the answer textbox
        return "";
      }
      //since we know question is valid at this point, store the question for next go-around
      previousQuestion = question;

      num = Math.round((answers.length - 1) * Math.random());

      return answers[num];
    }
    //  End -->
  </script>

  <form>
    <b style="color:white">What would you like to know?</b>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <input type=text name=question size=35>

    <input type=button name=ask value="Ask the 8 ball" onClick="if 
(this.form.question.value!='') this.form.answer.value = fortune(this.form.question.value);"><b style="color:white">

<br>The 8 ball says:</b>
    <br>

    <br>
    <input type=text name=answer size=35>
  </form>
```

Comment: No problem. I added comments to show what I'm doing at each step. Also if this answered your question could you please mark it as accepted answer.